# How can I avoid repetitive if-else when validating fields in a DTO?

Tags: java, lambda

StudentDTO class having around 20 string attributes and each need to validate whether mandatory or not based on the logic given below in comments. This will make  update method lengthy with too many if else's. Exception message should change based on the property evaluating. This code use Java 11.

```
  // all fields except lastUpdated  are string
    public Student populateStudent(final StudentDTO studentDTO) {
        Student student = new Student();
        boolean dataUpdated = false;
        /*
        If mandatory parameter is:
            1.) null : parameter is not updating
            2.) empty : validate and throw an exception
            3.) blank : validate and throw an exception
         */
        if (isEmptyOrBlank(studentDTO.getName())) {
            handleBadParam("Bad student name");
        } else {
            if (studentDTO.getName() != null) {
                student.setName(studentDTO.getName());
                dataUpdated = true;
            }
        }
        if (isEmptyOrBlank(studentDTO.getBirthday())) {
            handleBadParam("Bad student birthday");
        } else {
            if (studentDTO.getBirthday() != null) {
                student.setBirthday(studentDTO.getBirthday());
                dataUpdated = true;
            }
        }

        // .... 20 other similar if-else statements later ....

        // if atleast one parameter updated then date should update
        if (dataUpdated) {
            student.setLastUpdated(new Date());
        }
        return student;
    }

    private boolean isEmptyOrBlank(String name) {
        return name != null && (name.isEmpty() || isBlank(name));
    }

    private void handleBadParam(String messgae) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(messgae);
    }

    private boolean isBlank(String name) {
        return (name.trim().length() == 0);
    }
```

Comment: I can see only one `if` - `else`

Comment: `name.isEmpty() || name.isEmpty()`?

Comment: I think this is an example of one method trying to do too many things.  Why is your update method trying to validate every field?  You should extract the data validation into one or more other methods.

Comment: You can do this with reflection and (optionally for more control) annotations. This allows you to e.g. loop over all methods named `getSomething` in your DTO class, do this logic in a single if-else in your loop, and call `"set"+Someting` for each on your target class. @Lino Yes, it's both valid code and valid code :P

Comment: Apart from custom exception message, seems like the logic could be something as simple as `return Optional.of(studentDTO)
                .filter(a -> isNotEmptyOrBlank(a.getName()))
                .filter(a -> isNotEmptyOrBlank(a.getBirthday()))
                .map(a -> new Student(a.getName(), a.getBirthday(), System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);` with the util to add to it `private boolean isNotEmptyOrBlank(String name) {
        return name != null && !name.isEmpty() && name.trim().length() != 0;
    }`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are validating your object.

I will not share any code example, I will just share an design opinion. By the way while designing your application, you should follow a design principle. So [SOLID design principles](https://stackify.com/solid-design-principles/) is the commonly accepted, and you can apply these principles to your app while designing it.

You may create a class like `StudentValidator` so it's job must be only validating the `Student` object. So you realize first principle of solid's single responsibility.

And also that StudentValidator class will have methods which validations you need. And after all that implementations, you can cover in a method for each validation or you may call them when needed line.

Also there are many design patterns to avoid `if-else` statements via implementing patterns. Like command pattern, using enums etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend to use the Java environment JSR 303 Bean Validation.The javax.validation packages provide developers with a standardized way of doing so. Fields that have to fulfill certain criteria receive the corresponding annotations, e.g. @NotNull, and these are then evaluated by the framework. Naturally, for checking more specific conditions, there is the possibility of creating custom annotations and validators.

You could refer to this https://dzone.com/articles/bean-validation-made-simple.

Comment: Attribute values can be null but can't be blank or empty. Bean validator NotEmpty and NotBlank internally check for nullability.  So it can't use here.